# Flask - cannot use Flask and Flask-mail instances from other files

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I'm currently building an application with Flask. I'm struggling to access Flask instance 'app' as well as Flask-mail instance 'mail'.

Below is how my project looks like:

```
└── my-project
    ├── application
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── admin
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── forms.py
    │   │   └── views.py
    │   ├── auth
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── forms.py
    │   │   └── views.py
    │   │   └── token.py
    │   │   └── email.py
    │   ├── home
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── views.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── static
    │   └── templates
    │       └──....
    │
    ├── config.py
    ├── instance
    │   └── config.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── README
    │   ├── alembic.ini
    │   ├── env.py
    │   ├── script.py.mako
    │   └── versions
    │       └── a1a1d8b30202_.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── run.py
```

Flask instance is created in run.py with create_app function (from

## run.py

```
import os

from application import create_app

config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')
app = create_app(config_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

## **application/__init__.py**

```
# third-party imports
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_mail import Mail
import stripe


# local imports
from config import app_config

# db variable initialization
db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()
LoginManager.user_loader

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')


    Bootstrap(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    mail = Mail(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app,db)

    from application import models

    from .admin import admin as admin_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(admin_blueprint, url_prefix='/admin')
    #the rest of the blueprint import goes here


    return app
```

What I want to do is to use 'app' and 'mail'. For example, in application/auth/token:

## application/auth/token.py

```
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer

from . import auth

def generate_confirmation_token(email):
    serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    return serializer.dumps(email, salt=app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'])

def confirm_token(token, expiration = 600):
    serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    try:
        email = serializer.loads(
            token,
            salt=app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'],
            max_age=expiration
        )
    except:
        return False
    return email
```

or in application/auth/email.py:

## application/auth/email.py

```
from flask_mail import Message

from . import auth

def send_mail(to, subject, template):
    msg = Message(
        subject,
        recipients=[to],
        html=template,
        sender=app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER']
    )
    mail.send(msg)
```

I need both of these function in application/aut/views.py

## application/auth/views.py

```
from flask import flash, redirect, render_template, url_for, request
from flask_login import login_required, login_user, logout_user
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
import datetime

from . import auth
from forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm
from .. import db
from ..models import User

@auth.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    """
    Handle requests to the /register route
    Add a user to the database through the registration form
    """
    form = RegistrationForm()
    form.id = 'form_signup' 
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(email=form.email.data,
                    #username=form.username.data,
                    first_name=form.first_name.data,
                    last_name=form.last_name.data,
                    password=form.password.data,
                    registered_on=datetime.datetime.now(),
                    confirmed=False,
                    premium=False)

        # add employee to the database
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("We've just sent you an email confirmation. Please activate you account to completly finish your registration", 'succes')

        token = generate_confirmation_token(user.email)
        confirm_url = url_for('auth.confirm_email', token=token, _external=True)
        html = render_template('auth/activate.html', confirm_url=confirm_url)
        subject = "Please confirm your email"
        send_email(user.email, subject, html)

        login_user(user)

        flash('A confirmation email has been sent via email.', 'success')

        # redirect to the login page
        #return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
        return redirect(url_for('home.homepage'))

    # load registration template
    return render_template('auth/register.html', form=form, title='Register')

@auth.route('/confirm/<token>')
@login_required
def confirm_email(token):
    try:
        email = confirm_token(token)
    except:
        flash('The confirmation link is invalid or has expired.', 'danger')
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first_or_404()
    if user.confirmed:
        flash('Account already confirmed. Please login.', 'succes')
    else:
        user.confirmed =True
        user.confirmed_on = datetime.datetime.now()
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("You've confirmed your account. Thanks!", 'succes')
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
```

What I get is an error 'global name app is not defined' or 'global name mail is not defined'. I tried to import the variable with from application import app which return me an import error 'cannot import app'

Thanks for your support

Comment: Please share the full trraceback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using an application factory you need to use the `.init_app` method on the `Flask-Mail` class like you did the `Flask-SQLAlchemy` class. `from application import app` will not work since you are never initializing an instance of the flask application until you call the `create_app` function in `run.py`

**application/__init__.py**

```
from flask_mail import Mail

mail = Mail()


def create_app(config_lvl):
    # stuff

    mail.init_app(app)
    # more stuff
    return app
```

Also you can use `current_app` to refer to the application instance instead of the instance itself as long as the block of code you use it in is being ran in a flask application. [Here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/#purpose-of-the-application-context) is a more in depth explanation.

**application/auth/email.py**

```
from application import mail  # you can now import the Mail() object
from flask_mail import Message
from flask import current_app  # use this to reference current application context

def send_email(to, subject, template):
    msg = Message(
        subject,
        recipients=[to],
        html=template,
        sender=current_app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER']
    )
    mail.send(msg)
```

**application/auth/token.py**

```
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer
from flask import current_app

def generate_confirmation_token(email):
    serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    return serializer.dumps(email, salt=current_app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'])

def confirm_token(token, expiration = 600):
    serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    try:
        email = serializer.loads(
            token,
            salt=current_app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'],
            max_age=expiration
        )
    except:
        return False
    return email
```

also should note that you don't need `from . import auth` in any of your modules under the `auth` blueprint except `views.py`

**EDIT**

Side note: You don't have to add the user to the session because it was added when you queried for it earlier in the route. I was unaware of this for the longest time myself.

```
@auth.route('/confirm/<token>')
@login_required
def confirm_email(token):
    try:
        email = confirm_token(token)
    except:
        flash('The confirmation link is invalid or has expired.', 'danger')
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first_or_404()
    if user.confirmed:
        flash('Account already confirmed. Please login.', 'success')
    else:
        user.confirmed = True
        user.confirmed_on = datetime.datetime.now()
      #  db.session.add(user) # can remove this
        db.session.commit()
        flash("You've confirmed your account. Thanks!", 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Adam. I still have a 'cannot import name send_email' error while importing the functions from the views :

from application.auth.email import send_email

Comment: What file is that in?

Comment: I call the function from application/auth/views.py file and this function is located in application/auth/email.py

Comment: try `from .email import send_email`

Comment: I try from .email import send_email:
__import__(module)
  File "/home/kevin/my-project/run.py", line 8, in <module>
    app = create_app(config_name)
  File "/home/kevin/my-project/application/__init__.py", line 51, in create_app
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
  File "/home/kevin/my-project/application/auth/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/kevin/my-project/application/auth/views.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .email import send_email
ImportError: cannot import name send_email

Comment: I inserted the token and email functions directly in application/auth/views.py but iI still cannot access my Flask instance named 'app'.
I am completely stuck in this project.. Thanks for helping

Comment: File "/home/kevin/~Envs/my-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/kevin/my-project/application/auth/views.py", line 70, in register
    token = generate_confirmation_token(user.email)
  File "/home/kevin/my-project/application/auth/views.py", line 32, in generate_confirmation_token
    serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
NameError: global name 'app' is not defined

Comment: Could you possibly post it to github? or is it a work related app?

Comment: https://github.com/noname34/flask-application
I removed sensitive information. Hope you have enough information to help me

Comment: Solve it. It simply was a misspelling. My function is send_email() and I was trying to import send_mail ....

Comment: Yeah looks like i had a typo in my answer. But other than that was this the correct answer to your issue?

Comment: Yes it was as I commented below. Thank you for your help @Adam!

Answer (score 1):

According to http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/ you have to use current_app  (from flask import current_app) to access your Flask instance for wherever in your application.
Then you can use your config variables: `current_app.config['DEBUG']` for instance.

Another point to consider when using application factories, create instance class instances outside of the 'create_app()' function. Then you have to use .init_app method:

Below is an example:

```
from flask_mail import Mail

mail= Mail()

def create_app():
    mail.init_app(app)
```

Comment: This has proven to me to be the easiest way to set this up.